# Angular Multi-select not working inside form

Tags: angular, forms

I'm trying to use multiselect in my angular project. but I don't know why the multiselect is not working inside form.

```
            <form #f="ngForm" method ="POST" (submit)="payBiller($event, f)">                        
                <div>                
                    <ng-select [items]="bItems" (change)="updateSelectedValues();" bindLabel="item_name"  [(ngModel)]="selectedBillerItems" multiple="true" placeholder="Select Category" ></ng-select>
                </div>
    
                <div *ngIf="selectedBillerItems?.length > 0" class ="row">
                    <span>Thanks for selecting</span>
                </div>    
            </form
```

But If I place the multi-select outside the form, it works

```
                 <div>                
                    <ng-select [items]="bItems" (change)="updateSelectedValues();" bindLabel="item_name"  [(ngModel)]="selectedBillerItems" multiple="true" placeholder="Select Category" ></ng-select>
                </div>
    
                <div *ngIf="selectedBillerItems?.length > 0" class ="row">
                    <spam>Thanks for selecting</span>
                </div>

              <form #f="ngForm" method ="POST" (submit)="payBiller($event, f)"></form>


              getSelectedValue(){
                console.log(this.selectedBillerItems);
              }
```

Comment: You have a typo at line <spam>Thanks for selecting</span>.

Comment: Please, try to reproduce the issue on https://stackblitz.com/. I'm trying an example with your code and there is no problem at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got a solution and the solution was quite simple. I simply added a name attribute to the ng-select element and my problem was solved. Here is the code

```
<ng-select [items]="bItems" (change)="updateSelectedValues();" bindLabel="item_name"  [(ngModel)]="selectedBillerItems" [multiple]="true" placeholder="Select Category" name="something" formControlName="bItems"></ng-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to add **formControlName** for ng-select if you are using it in the form tag,
and for selecting multiple values you need add [multiple] = true

```
 <ng-select [items]="bItems" (change)="updateSelectedValues();" bindLabel="item_name"  [(ngModel)]="selectedBillerItems" [multiple]="true" placeholder="Select Category" formControlName="bItems"></ng-select>
```

you can refer https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-select/ng-select link for more info.

Comment: What's the purpose of the formControlName="bItems"? When I added it, the form didn't show again

Comment: As I mentioned if you are using the ng-select inside form and as a form value then you need to add formcontrolname.